# WSE X.509 Certificate Tool cannot access local computer personal store

Tags: x509certificate, web-services-enhancements

I am trying to configure security on a certificate using the WSE X.509 Certificate Tool version 2.0. The certificate is installed in the local computer personal certificate store.

On one of our web servers choosing "Local Computer" for Certificate Location does not present an option for "Personal" in the store name dropdown. This option does appear on our other web servers.

Any idea why the personal certificate store is not visible?

Comment: I have had the same problem with WSE X.509 Certificate Tool 3.0 on Windows 7 64 bit. Version 2.0 worked for me though.

Comment: @Ronald: Thanks for that info. It helped me with a similar problem.